# How to test a component which uses React Autosuggest

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I am trying to test a React component which is similar to the following

```
const MyComponent = ({ onChangCallMe, onSelectCallMe }) => {

// onChangCallMe -> sets the state of some other component  
// onSelectCallMe -> -> sets the state of some other component

return (
    <Autosuggest
        onChange={ value => onChangCallMe(value)}
        onSelect={ selected => onSelectCallMe(selected) }
    />)
}
```

How to test this component? and make sure that the onChangCallMe, onSelectCallMe are being called properly?

The problem is if I mock the Autosuggest like this `jest.mock('./react-autosuggest')` then it would not show the actual output and also it won't listen to the different events such as ChangeEvent and SelectEvent.

Comment: When you mock out Autosuggest, what do you *replace* it with? Give a [mre].

Comment: @jonrsharpe I replace it with, `jest.mock('./react-autosuggest')`

Comment: For one thing that's not the path to mock an import from node_modules. For another you probably want to supply an implementation.

Comment: @lynxx is Autosuggest a npm package (under node_modules), or you implemented it ant it's part of source code?

Comment: @yaya it's a npm package.

Comment: @lynxx can you say the name of the package? cause `react-autosuggest` doesn't seem to have the props you passed to it?

Comment: @yaya No, `react-autosuggest` doesn't. But I made my own compoenet that uses `react-autosuggest`. Its very similar to the compoenent shown in the post.

Comment: @lynxx what exactly you want to test? you want to test if : 1. `onChangCallMe` on this component will get called when the child (`Autosuggest`) fires the `onChange` 
 (this way to can test this component separately, and the children separately) ? Or 2. you want to test the components together , and check if the `onChangCallMe` and `onSelectCallMe` will get called after user changes the option (testing this component, as well as the childs, in one place.) ?